# keep value form value in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with writing my first Wordpress plugin.

I'm creating a form for a settings page, however i don't know how to **save the values**.
I need to do that for the following 2 reasons,

1. I need the selected option to stay selected when you reload the page
2. I need to use the value for later use.

can anybody help me with that?

**Code:**

```
function e_option_page() {

?>

    <form action="" id="testimonialsform" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="Option" value="Option 1">Option 1
        <input type="radio" name="Option" value="Option 2">Option 2
        <input type="radio" name="Option" value="Option 3">Option 3
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['Option'])){    
            echo "You have selected :".$_POST['Option'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
        }//End isset
    }//End isset
}//End function


function e_setting_page() {
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=testimonials', 'Settings', 'Settings', 'edit_posts', "settings",'e_option_page');
}

add_action('admin_menu' , 'e_setting_page');
```

Comment: ternary operator with sessions should do the trick.

Comment: use a session variable if you want to use into someother page

Answer (score 0):

Submit the form and process the values in the PHP script.

```
PHP Processing Script:
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION[ 'option' ] = $_POST[ 'Option' ];
?>

Form Page
<?php session_start(); ?>
<form action="" id="testimonialsform" method="post">
  <input type="radio" name="Option" value="Option 1" <?php echo ( $_SESSION[ 'option' ] == "Option 1" ? 'checked' : '' ); ?>>Option 1
  <input type="radio" name="Option" value="Option 2" <?php echo ( $_SESSION[ 'option' ] == "Option 2" ? 'checked' : '' ); ?>>Option 2
  <input type="radio" name="Option" value="Option 3" <?php echo ( $_SESSION[ 'option' ] == "Option 3" ? 'checked' : '' ); ?>>Option 3
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The ternary if statement works like this:

```
echo ( 1 = 1 ? "true" : "false" );
```

https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Comment: hello, it works but this warnings appear:

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\formatting.php:5011) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\elevation-testimonials\elevation-testimonials.php on line 122

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\formatting.php:5011) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\elevation-testimonials\elevation-testimonials.php on line 122

Comment: how about removing session_start(); since wordpress starts a session once you logon

Comment: dont' worry about the above comment...hello, it works great..but i have a question..the value is store somewhere? because i need to access that value

Comment: The variable can be accessed anywhere, just `echo $_SESSION[ 'option' ]` where ever you want.  This will continue to work until you either remove or reset the session variable.

Comment: this works only for me..but other people can't see the same way i do..is something about session??